# Set hash to fancybox cause error

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fancybox

I using fancybox in my project

Here is code

```
 $(".hotel_gallery").attr("data-fancybox", "quick-view")
  .fancybox({
    prevEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    closeBtn: true,
    arrows: true,
    hash: false,
    beforeShow(): void {
      this.title = this.src;
    },
    afterLoad(instance, current ): void{
      if ( instance.group.length > 1 && current.$content ) {
        current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="javascript:;">→</a><a data-fancybox-previous class="button-previous" href="javascript:;">←</a>');
      }
      current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-close class="button-close" href="javascript:;">×</a>');
    },
  });
```

I try to set `hash: false`

But i have error now

> Argument of type '{ prevEffect: string; nextEffect: string; closeBtn: boolean; arrows: boolean; hash: boolean; befo...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'prevEffect' does not exist in type 'any[]'.

without `hash: false` , I don't have this.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: yeah. I'm using typescript @Janis

Comment: Then you need "TypeScript Declaration File". I do not know if there is one available somewhere.

Comment: But, all other properties are working@ Janis

Comment: I solve trouble @Janis

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this problem with code rewriting

Here is code

```
 ($(".hotel_gallery") as any).attr("data-fancybox", "gallery")
  .fancybox({
    prevEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    closeBtn: true,
    arrows: true,
    hash: false,
    beforeShow(): void {
      this.title = this.src;
    },
    afterLoad(instance, current ): void {
      if ( instance.group.length > 1 && current.$content ) {
        current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="javascript:;">→</a><a data-fancybox-previous class="button-previous" href="javascript:;">←</a>');
      }
      current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-close class="button-close" href="javascript:;">×</a>');
    },
  });
```